# how to pass text by adding double quotes before and after in android

Tags: java, android, json, string, double-quotes

I want to pass some text by adding double quotes before and after.

I have a retrieved some text(url) from my json array like https://xyzabc and i have stored it in a string.

now i have to add some certificate and some response to that url and trying to retrieve some another data from it(new URL).

Here Iam  trying to pass like String newUrl = oldurl+response+certificate

And i have to pass the url in double quotes(must in double quotes) if iam passing like String newUrl = "oldurl+response+certificate", the total is considering as one string so i have to append double quotes before and after the newUrl string without make it as a single String.

I have tried some "\"newUrl""\ but it doent work for me...Suggest me some solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
newUrl = "\""+oldurl+response+certificate+"\"";
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

Use temporary special character in  string `literal` and convert it into `quotation` like

```
String newUrl = ("$"+oldurl+response+certificate+"$").replaceAll('$','"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression -

```
String str="\"yourstring here\""
```